# Swift observe value for var change in protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift protocol defined as:

```
 public protocol DisplayBuffer: class {
      func displayBuffer(_ pixelBuffer:CVPixelBuffer)      
      var myVar:MyClass {get set}
}
```

and in view controller, I have:

```
private var glView:(UIView & DisplayFrame)?
```

My problem is I need to observe change in myVar in the controller, i.e. change in value of glView.myVar. What is the right way of doing this in Swift 4?

Comment: What's `DisplayVideoFrame`? Regardless, you should use property observers (`didSet` or `willSet`).

Comment: It's actually DisplayFrame, sorry about that. You mean sending delegate messages back to controller in didSet?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution to this problem. myVar may not be observable. It depends on the specific implementation of the conforming class. The DisplayBuffer protocol doesn't promise an observable property here (there's no way for a protocol to promise that).

Comment: The implementing class must make `myVar` KVO compliant. This will be true by default if it's an NSObject subclass that implements `myVar` as a auto-synthesized `@property` (ObjC) or `@objc dynamic var` (Swift). See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift